# WSUS All updates view

Tags: wsus, update

As you can see in the next screenshot, there's a lot of drivers update for a lot of different network adapters. So these updates are all updates available from microsoft, regardless of my computer environment, am it right?
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all WSUS updates are from webservers owned and/or controlled by MS. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: i mean if i only network card A, but in the All updates view i can see drivers update for Network card B, C... it's normal because in this view, we see all updates available from microsoft. Am i right?

Comment: Correct, Microsoft does not know what hardware you own.